# Run-time error '1004' while protecting sheets

Tags: vba, excel

Running a system that is triggered by a control box. The code unprotects nearly all the sheets in the program using the following code (no problems):

```
Sub UnprotectSheets()

    Dim wks As Worksheet

    For Each wks In Worksheets
        If wks.Name Like "Source Data Table" Or wks.Name Like "Permit Route Dashboard" _
        Or wks.Name Like "Administrative Tasks" Or wks.Name Like "RP Calculation" Then GoTo Nextwks
        wks.Unprotect Password:="Password"
Nextwks:
    Next

End Sub
```

The program then conducts an analysis. At the end, I want to protect the same sheets, using the following code

```
Sub ProtectSheets()

    Dim wks As Worksheet

    For Each wks In Worksheets
        If wks.Name Like "Source Data Table" Or wks.Name Like "Permit Route Dashboard" _
        Or wks.Name Like "Administrative Tasks" Or wks.Name Like "RP Calculation" Then GoTo Nextwks
        wks.Protect Password:="Password"
Nextwks:
    Next

End Sub
```

However - I keep receiving the following error every time:

> Run-time error '1004' Method 'Protect' of object _Worksheet' failed

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Which line produces the error?

Comment: wks.Protect Password:="Password"

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to protect an already protected sheet. Thus, simply run this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim wks As Worksheet

    For Each wks In Worksheets
        If wks.ProtectContents Then
            Debug.Print wks.Name & " is protected!"
        Else
            Debug.Print wks.Name & " is not protected!"
        End If
    Next wks

End Sub
```

Then go to the immediate window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) and take a look at the report written there. It should look like this:

```
Sheet1 is not protected!
Sheet2 is protected!
```

In general, try to avoid `GoTo` in VBA (and in every programming language), unless it is for error-catching. People become mad when they see these.

Comment: Wish I could +1 the "People become mad when they see these." bit twice.

Comment: The UnprotectSheets module above (in the original post) unprotects every sheet at the beginning. The ProtectSheets module is ran at the end of the program so the sheet should not already be protected when trying to protect it?

Comment: @CoreyBeck - it does not unprotect every sheet, there is some if condition, thus some are excluded. What did you get as a result in the immediate window?

Comment: Correct, it doesn't unprotect every sheet but the same if statement is used for both the unprotect and protect sheet code. I receive the error for sheets not in the condition statement

Comment: @CoreyBeck - What did you get as a result in the immediate window?

Comment: I didn't end up using the Debug portion, just the wks.ProtectContents and the code works fine now. Just confused about why mine didn't initially.